# Filter List items in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

I need to remove city names 5 characters or less from cities list:

The below code works, but I feel the code is too long and there should be another method I can use to cut down the length of the code.

```
cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Tokyo", "Dubai", "Mexico 
City", "São Paulo", "Hyderabad"]
count = 0
loop = 0

print("City List:",cities)

for x in range(len(cities)):
    if len(cities[x]) <= 5:
        cities[x] = 'small'

for x in range(len(cities)):
    if cities[x] == 'small':
        count += 1

while loop < count:
    for x in cities:
        if x == 'small':
            cities.remove(x)
            loop += 1

print("Filtered:",cities)
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way would be a list comprehension

```
cities = [city for city in cityes if len(city) < 6]
```

This is eqivalent to

```
cities_filterd = []
for city in cities:
    if len(city) < 6:
        cities_filterd.append(city)
```

cities_filterd will then contain the citiey with a lenth smaller than 6.

Comment: The shortest? In the eye of my answer ? :D At most, they are similar I'd say.

Comment: Yeah you are right, list comprehensions would be considers me pythonic than using filter and lambda functions and list comprehensions are more easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter:

```
filtered_cities = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 5, cities)
```